# Flattening nested list

Tags: python, list

I have hundreds of rows of data that look like this:

```
[[u' 16 '], [u'1x23'], [u'Mr Test', u' (5)'], [u'John Smith'], [u'54.5'], [], [u'10%'], [u'40%'], [u'$26,503']]
```

Some of the values are nested and some also are empty.

I'm trying to massage it to be like this:

```
['16', '1x23', 'Mr Test', '(5)', 'John Smith', '54.5', '', '10%', '40%', '$26,503']
```

I've tried some ideas found on here like flattening, including the following routine:

```
def traverse(o, tree_types=(list, tuple)):
    if isinstance(o, tree_types):
        for value in o:
            for subvalue in traverse(value):
                yield subvalue
    else:
        yield o
```

This worked for some tables I've already parsed but only when there are no empty values.

Comment: for clarification, do you want empty values to result in `""` as i have seen you write, or ignored?

Comment: Show us the code you used to build `data`. Maybe we can suggest a way to build it in the form you want directly.

Comment: One thing to watch out for: not all of your sub-lists are the same size. Some have one element, and others have two; if you flatten the list, then you may lose relationships such as between columns of a file, and end up indexing the wrong thing. A better question is: what do you want to do with the list? There may be an alternate data structure worth considering.

Comment: Could you use some of the info here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python

Comment: Whatever you do, don't look to see if this has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Flatten+list+of+lists+in+Python&submit=search

Comment: @InbarRose, the empty values still need to be there. stummjr's answer works perfect for my needs.

Comment: @abought, actually the flattening out is ok as long as the empty values stay in place. The rows need further massaging then zipped into a dict structure, before display, logging and finally into a db.

Comment: @msw, went down that path already, that's where I got 'traverse' come from. stummjr's mod works like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your only problem is with empty values, you could check for it inside first `if`:

```
def traverse(o, tree_types=(list, tuple)):
    if isinstance(o, tree_types):
        if len(o) == 0:
            yield ''
        for value in o:
            for subvalue in traverse(value):
                yield subvalue
    else:
        yield o
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
sum((item or [""] for item in a), [])
```

Weird huh?

Comment: Nicely poached from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python ;)

Comment: Actually I knew about it from long ago from #python

Comment: I don't doubt it; I'm not being serious

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick (even with empty values):

```
import operator
def flatten(a):
    return reduce(operator.add, a)
```

Comment: This drops the empty `''` values.